# I have a stomach ulcer and can't use pepper what else can I use

Tags: pepper

I was just diagnosed with a stomach ulcer and need to know what I can season my food with.  I normally use black pepper and/or Slap Ya Mama (similiar to Tony's seasoning).

Comment: Eileen, welcome! Please note that we can’t offer medical advice, what works for your condition and what needs to be avoided should be discussed with your healthcare provider.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I can't eat anything spicy but don't want food that is bland with no flavor.  I've tried the Roasted Garlic & Herbs on my chicken which wasn't bad but I like beef and different kinds of soup

Comment: This question is problematic in multiple ways. Health advice (listing spices „ok“ for ulcer patients) is off topic. Suggesting non-spicy flavors is ultimately opinion-based and flavor-pairing, both off topic. Each interpretation means the question is not a good fit for the SE system.

Comment: @Nick012000 thank you for catching my bad choice of duplicate. As Stephie stated, the question is not a good fit, but now it isn't misleadingly closed. And the good news for Eileen is that, this being subjective, any seasoning has the potential to become a good choice for her.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use seasonings that aren't spicy.

If you want to season your food to be flavourful, but you can't eat spicy foods due to a medical condition, then season your foods with flavours that aren't spicy. There's literally a whole world of different flavors out there for you to try - for chicken, for instance, off of the top of my head, you could try pairing with onions and tomato or a creamy cheese sauce for a flavor like Italian cuisine, with salty and umami flavors in a stir fry or noodle dish, with sugary fruit jams for something like American Thanksgiving turkey dish.

Our mouth has taste buds capable of detecting the five basic tastes of sweet, sour, salty, bitter, and umami, so feel free to experiment with different combinations of flavours until you find one you like!